# mongoose error object‏ does not show name in postman or console.log()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I face an interesting challenge in my error handling with mongoose and express. when I return the mongoose error(casterror or validation error) I can't see 'name' property in postman. even when I `console.log(err)` there is no name property on error object. but when I write: console.log(err.name) it returns it correctly. also when i make copy object, I can't even log copy object name property:
`const error = { ...err };` console.log(error.name) => return` undefined.  after some searching, I found something name enumerable. and I understood when enumerable is false on the property I can't see that in console.log or in for loop and etc(like a stack of err). I try to change  enumerable to true and I come to succeed on the stack and I can see that :

```
 Object.defineProperty(err, 'stack', {
  enumerable: true,
});
```

//now satck is sho in console.log(err);) but when I do it on name property there is no change and even worse. because now console.log(err.name) return undefined. I want to know what is the reason?

Comment: Why would you log `error` to the console from the server? I mean you just need to return errors from the `Server` to the `Client` and let it handle that

Comment: yes you are right but it is not the case here.because  I cant see the 'name' property in the result that returned to client I just log error for test

Comment: Also, note that `console.log` has nothing to do with `javascript` at all neither is `javascript` thing but rather `browsers` implementations. Try logging the error to a file and see what happens

Comment: first I return the error as JSON in postman and after that just for a little test use console.log. and also Thanks for your great information